# VBA Using ODBCConnection.RefreshDate Resuts in Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

Due to the way workbooks I'm working with are set up, there are many different connections created within them, but only one of the connections is valid.  The valid connection will be the only connection with a refresh date, so I'm trying to set up a null check using an Excel macro to find this.  The code I have so far is:

```
For Each c2 In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
If Not IsNull(c2.ODBCConnection.RefreshDate) Then  
Blah Blah  
End If
```

At the null check I encounter Run-time error '1004'; Application-defined or object-defined error.  I'm wondering if this has to do with a missing reference?  Or possibly something else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Try swapping IsNull for IsNothing?

Comment: I would rather use `On Error Resume Next` before you loop!

Comment: Is Nothing still gives the same error and 'On Error Resume Next' removes the error but still grabs the wrong connection, it doesn't seem to make the null/nothing check work.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` allows you to check the property without stopping on the error - but the error still happens.  After checking `RefreshDate`, check to see if `Err = 0`; if so, you managed to retrieve the date successfully.  If it's 1004, the connection doesn't have a valid value for `RefreshDate`.

Comment: Checking the 'Err', it does appear as 0 for each `RefreshDate`, and appears as 1004 every time there isn't a `RefreshDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is caused by there being no clean null value for the `Date` type.  Instead, MS throws an error when you try to access it.

One way to deal with this is to retrieve the value into a variable, but wrap that retrieval in an error handler block:

```
Dim d As Date
For Each c2 In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    On Error Resume Next
    d = c2.OLEDBConnection.RefreshDate
    If Err = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "No date"
    ElseIf Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unknown error (" & Err.Number & "): " & Err.Description
    Else
        MsgBox CStr(d)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next
```

The `On Error Resume Next` indicates that the following code shouldn't break on an error; the `On Error Goto 0` indicates that normal (system) error handling should resume.

Comment: This worked!  I trimmed it down a bit to only use the error code in an if then statement:
`For Each c2 In ActiveWorkbook.Connections`
`On Error Resume Next`
`If Not IsNull(c2.ODBCConnection.RefreshDate) Then`
`If Not Err = 1004 Then`

Comment: Good! Take note of Remou's comment about not all connections being ODBC; I'm assuming you're sure they are in your case, but you should really check it as indicated.

Comment: +1 I have been testing, and it seems that the RefreshDate property simply does not exist for some connections, so this would appear to be the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not all connections are ODBC, how about:

```
For Each c2 In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    If c2.Type = xlConnectionTypeODBC Then
        If Not IsNull(c2.ODBCConnection.RefreshDate) Then
        ''Blah Blah
        End If
    End If
Next
```

However, I am not sure that it will ever be null: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837641(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Evaluating `c2.ODBCConnection` in the VBA watch window shows the property as unavailable; my guess is that it doesn't properly support returning a null value (although it could return `vbNull`, MS doesn't seem to implement it that way, apart from with objects)

Comment: If it doesn't support returning a null value, do you know of any other way to get this to work?  What if I did something like if the refresh date > Jan 1 1900, or something like that.